# Keep Text Fixed on One Line - Mobile Slide In Menu CSS

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if there is a style that keeps the text within a div locked into a straight line no matter what the width of the container is? (No stacked text)

See I have a slide-in menu that is working nicely, the buttons look great, but there's just one thing that's visually offputting and it's that the text is stacked up as it slides out and then flattens out as the width of the container is increased to full screen.

Here's the HTML of a menu item:

```
<div class="navigation-menu-slide-in-10">
 <a href="account.html">Account</a>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS of the menu item:

```
.navigation-menu-slide-in-10 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 6vh;
 background-color: transparent;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: left;
 align-items: center;
 font-family: bahnschrift;
 font-size: 28px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.navigation-menu-slide-in-10 a {
 padding-left: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

As for how the menu unfolds, here's the Javascript. The button is clicked and then goes out of visual existence. Then the other button is made visible within my slide-out-menu. Then the slide-out-menu is made visible. And then is increased to 100% width with a transition delay which acts as an animation.

```
function mobileNavigationButtonOn() {
        document.getElementById("mobileNavigationButtonOff").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("mobileNavigationButtonOn").style.display = "flex";
        document.getElementById("mobileNavigationMenuSlideIn").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("mobileNavigationMenuSlideIn").style.width = "100%";
}
```

Oh, and I guess the CSS for the slide-in-menu might be pertinent too. Here is that:

```
.navigation-menu-slide-in {
          width: 0%;
          height: 100%;
          background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3300, #ff7700);
          position: fixed;
          visibility: hidden;
          transition-duration: 0.6s;
          transition-property: width;
          overflow-x: hidden;
          z-index: 3;
}
```

Yeah, so I'm looking for a way to keep the text fixed into a straight line. Thanks.

Comment: Animate the position of the container not its width.

Comment: But I like how the buttons and images roll out with the width adjustment. I'm looking for a way to keep the width animation but fix the text flat.

Comment: Nevermind, found the style that does the trick ... white-space: nowrap;

Comment: That's a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I found the style that works if anyone is having this same issue...

white-space: nowrap;